# Struts2 checkbox not appearing in JSON if unchecked

Tags: jquery, json, struts2

I have a form that works correctly except for one part.
There's a checkbox made with struts2 tags that returns true/false for checked/unchecked.
When it is not checked, it does not appear in the JSON at all.

```
<s:checkbox name="chk1" id="chk1" fieldValue="true" theme="simple" />
<s:checkbox name="chk2" id="chk2" fieldValue="true" theme="simple" />
```

if chk1 is checked and chk2 is unchecked, the JSON output is :

```
Object { name="chk1", value="true"}
Object { name="__checkbox_chk1", value="true"}
Object { name="__checkbox_chk2", value="true"}
```

what I'm looking for is :

```
Object { name="chk1", value="true"}
Object { name="__checkbox_chk1", value="true"}
Object { name="chk2", value="false"}
Object { name="__checkbox_chk2", value="true"}
```

Its struts2 generated hidden object is there "__checkbox_chk2" but the actual "chk2" isn't.

To be clear, both the 'chk's and the '__checkbox_chk's are present in the HTML, but only the 'chk's that are checked are in the JSON.

Any ideas?

Here's my JQuery JSON:

```
var dataVar ;
dataVar =   $("#formWithChks").serializeArray();
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "url", 
    data: dataVar, 
    success: function(data) { 
        // does something
        }
```

Comment: checkbock interceptor needed to remove ____parameters

Comment: what would the interceptor remove?

Comment: These `__checkbox_xxx` is a garbage, chb interceptor collects it before you put it to JSON.

Comment: thanks, i'll look into that. any reason why the unchecked box isn't showing up in the json?

Answer (score 0):

> any reason why the unchecked box isn't showing up in the json

The unchecked checkbox isn't bound to the action property, or it's bound to another property via the checkbox interceptor. It is the same as checked checkbox property. Whatever you are puting into JSON it depends on serializer. Struts2 uses [json plugin](http://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html) to serialize objects to json.

Comment: I've added my jquery into the main post. I'm using .serializeArray to turn the form that contains both checkboxes into JSON

Comment: You should not use `.serializeArray`, because you are not getting JSON and you don't need it. Try to use `.serialize`.

Comment: @Freigheist `serializeArray()` will not give you JSON, but it's converted to JSON on the server when you return a json result.

Comment: Do you have any other question?